# Hierarchical axis with ordinal scale

Tags: d3.js

I would like to know, if there is existing code or best practices to realize ordinal axis with a certain hierarchy. Perhaps a example shows, what I mean. I try to realize a Business Support Map like shown in the following image (the upper part, without the legend):

[image: Business Support Map]

In essence this is a X-Y matrix with cells. The cell coordinates (Acquisition, Headquater, etc.) define the parent layer of the hierarchy. Within each cell there is child ordinal hierarchy of the cell elements. Later on pan and zoom, as well as the addition of layers, which show KPIs, indicators and aggregated data should be easy.

What is here a good combination of scale and axis? Is it easier to build a custom layout?